# is it possible to split data while moving it from one excel file to another in python? Pandas or openpyxl

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl, data-conversion

Essentially I need to translate one excel document into another.

Both sheets are formatted differently, but contain most of the same information - however in sheet 1, some data is formatted in a different way.

For Example "Name" in Sheet 1, and "First Name" "Last Name" in Sheet 2

is it possible to have my script do this for me?  What about looking for seperators like a comma to split "Address" into "Street" "city" "state" "zip" -- or is that best done post-translate using Excel tools.

I've been able to read rows directly using openpyxl with code like this:

```
    step = 2
    read_start_row = 4
    write_start_row = 3
    amount_of_rows = 30

    for i in range(0, amount_of_rows, step):
        #copy from wb1
        c = ws1.cell(row=read_start_row+i, column=4)
        #paste in ws2
        ws2.cell(row=write_start_row+(i/step), column=4, value=c.value)
```

but not sure where to start when trying to also alter the data.

Comment: You can split a Pandas column based on any delimiter including space, e.g a column with Header 'Name' and cell 'John Doe' can be split on the space into two new columns 'First' and 'Last' if that's what you want. Openpyxl can read a cell a split the value into two or more cells when writing to another cell again based on a delimiter as it copies each cell in a row.

Comment: What about styling, font, fill colours etc If these are not required then splitting the columns with Pandas and writing back to Excel is probably easier but if you're wanting to copy the cell styling as well as the data then Openpyxl could obtain this detail and update the cell as it copies/splits the data. I don't see that updating the sheet post-translate would be better since your likely still going to need to read in and write out to a sheet either way.

Comment: definitely don't need to worry about the styling - splitting and writing back to excel is probably the easiest/simplest thing to do here!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Be more specific in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick example if just copying the data.

The Example sheet has two columns; 'Name' and 'Address' where;
Name includes "First" and "Last" name separated by space
Address includes "Street" "City" "State" and "Zip" separated by comma

[image]

The example code reads the source Excel sheet splits the two columns into the constituents and writes the result back to the destinaton sheet

```
import pandas as pd


### Read data from source sheet
df = pd.read_excel('source.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

### Split the necessary columns on the delimiters
df[['First', 'Last']] = df['Name'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)  # Delimiter is space
df[['Street', 'City', 'State', 'Zip']] = df['Address'].str.split(', ', n=3, expand=True)  # Delimiter is comma

### Drop the now unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(['Name', 'Address'], axis=1)

### Reorder columns, probably not needed in this case but ensures the columns are in correct order.
df = df[['First', 'Last', 'Street', 'City', 'State', 'Zip']] 

### Write to the destination sheet, start row 2 (startrow 1), drop index and headers
with pd.ExcelWriter('dest.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=1, index=False, header=False)
```

Resultant dataframe

```
   First   Last          Street     City State         Zip
0  Mavis   West  421 E DRACHMAN   TUCSON    AZ  85705-7598
1   John  Spurs     100 MAIN ST  SEATTLE    WA       98104
2   Jack   East   105 KROME AVE    MIAMI    FL  33185 3700
```

In this example the destination Sheet contains the headers already on row 1 (note this is row 0 for to_excel). For this since writing to an existing sheet which already contains data (Headers) we use 'mode=a' (append) which requires Openpyxl as the engine.
The to_excel write excludes the Headers from the dataframe being they already exist, however if preferred the destination sheet could be empty and the headers written along with the columns.
[image]

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to use something with headers as in your example, basically translating from one systems output into another's input here, so I think that will work for me! I'll test it when I get some down time this coming week!